# best practice of naming flink uid to operator

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Is there a best practice of naming the `UID` for operator ?
can it be something simple like

```
stream.flatMap(new FlatMapFunc).uid("1")
    .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new TimestampExtractor).uid("2")
    .keyBy(r => r.key )
    .timeWindow(Time.minutes(10))
    .allowedLateness(Time.minutes(30))
    .process(new ProcessFunc).uid("3")
```

or there are some rules/recommendations of naming the uid's ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no naming convention for UID, but in our team we use the same value that we use in the operator.name(). The name value is used to render the operator box in the Flink UI

I that way we have code like this that is semantic and simple for us:

```
        streamExecutionEnvironment
        .addSource(new KafkaConsumer(kafkaConsumerOptions))
        .name("Kafka topic reader").uid("Kafka topic reader")
        .filter(new CreatedBy("my uncle"))
        .name("Created by my uncle filter").uid("Created by my uncle filter")
        .map(new ToInvoice())
        .name("To invoice mapper").uid("To invoice mapper")
```

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, you can use any string for the UID, as long as it's (obviously) unique for your workflow. But I think, going forward, Flink will provide better access to the savepoint data, which would include the UIDs. So then you'd want to use a more descriptive name, maybe in combination with a number to help ensure uniqueness.

Answer (score 2):

Each `uid` must be unique, otherwise job submissions will fail, so it helps to have a defined formatting style. [Flink docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/upgrading.html#matching-operator-state) get into detail about the importance of `uid` naming. It also suggested to use `.name` with `.uid` in order to have a named operator for logging and metrics.

One possible style is to use interpolated strings to craft a unique `uid` per operator. [Ezequiel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57165525/6293467) has a good naming standard..

**An example:**

If the operator were a map function to change e-mail addresses to domains and the source event was from a kafka topic named `emailEvents`

`mapEmailAddressToDomain($emailEvents)`